# Plugin sonarqube for openedge connection problem

Tags: java, sonarqube, openedge, progress-4gl, appserver

Lately i developed a sonaraqube plugin for openedge :
I wrote the rules with the language progress `4gl` and then I invoked the rules from `java` using appserver from `openedge` and it worked when I did a local test (`java`) but when I install the plugin in `sonarqube` an error appears

```
jvm 1    | 2020.08.13 20:48:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.3]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-7.3\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\sonarqube-7.3\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube-7.3\temp\sq-process2497102236075814669properties
jvm 1    | 2020.08.13 20:48:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2020.08.13 20:48:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2020.08.13 20:48:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
jvm 1    | 2020.08.13 20:48:26 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x066f5f28, L:/127.0.0.1:53117 - R:/127.0.0.1:9009]], closing connection
jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Une connexion existante a d¹ Ûtre fermÚe par lÆh¶te distant
```

this is my class conection :

```
    public class ConnectionAppServer  {
      OpenProcObject opo=null;   
      OpenAppObject oao=null;
    public   OpenProcObject connection(String ruleProc) {
      try {
    this.oao = 
 OpenEdgeAPSConnector.getOpenAppObjectInstance("AppServerDC://localhost:3090");
      } catch (Open4GLException | IOException | InterruptedException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("erreur de connection");
      }
      try {
        this.opo = oao.createPO(ruleProc);
      } catch (Open4GLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      return this.opo;
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?
I am blocked since weeks on this please help .
I start thinking that `sonarqube` doesn't accept connections inside plugins :(

Comment: it is very difficult to predict the problem with the provided information. Did you check the appserver logs (both broker and server)? You can also increase the logging level on the appserver side to get more details of the failure.

Comment: apsserver works fine because I tested at the maven plugin : I created a test file and got the desired scan result, but the sonarqube get an error when I install the plugin .

Comment: if there is an issue wit SonarQube, then I think it is better to contact SonarQube support.

Comment: your connecting to localhost, is everything on the same host ? try to replace localhost with real host or ip address

Comment: I tried and the same error :( :( :(